# How to create another brand new React app folder outside the existing React folder?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I already have create a project called my-app in React. Now I want to create another project independent to the first project. I tried to use command `create-react-app` but the project I created is within the first project. Is there any other commands I can use to create the second project?

Comment: Move up a directory and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

i think that is because you called create-react-app inside the directory of first project folder
you need to go outside the directory and then call create your app
in your terminal type `cd ../` press enter and then type `create-react-app app-name`